# JavaFX : Style combobox popup list text color and selected item color?

Tags: css, javafx, combobox

I have problem with styling `ComboBox` in css. I don't know how to change font color of selected item fx (2 people from black color to red), and how to set color effect when you point mouse on the current choice.

css code:

```
.combo-box
 {
  -fx-background-image:url("people_button.jpg");
  -fx-text-fill: red;
  -fx-min-width: 128;
  -fx-min-height: 48;

 }
.combo-box-popup .list-view
 {
   -fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
   -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
   -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 8, 0.0 , 0 , 0 );
 }
.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell
 {
-fx-background-color: #ececec;
-fx-text-fill: #9a9a9a;
-fx-font-family: Oxygen Light;
 }
```

and java code:

```
ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox();
combo.setVisibleRowCount(5);
combo.setItems(observableList);
combo.setValue("1 person");
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the pseudo-class `hover` to your style sheet :

```
.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:hover {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

For adding a color to the selected item, use the pseudo-class `selected` :

```
.combo-box .cell:selected {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

Comment: cool, it's working for pointing mouse, but what about default value which is displaying which black color i want to be able to change color

Comment: Which default value are you talking about? Can you please explain?

Comment: yes in a picture is "2 people" with black colors, in list view rest options has gray color. I want to change "2 people"  color to something else

Comment: @krychuq Added a solution